# Unhandled exception at 0x0A35D340 (libpq.dll)

Tags: c++, postgresql, visual-studio-2013

this exception is my problem:
Unhandled exception at 0x0A35D340 (libpq.dll), its doesn't always appear but somethimes. This appear when my program executes the query insert on postgresql. I prepare my query in this way:

```
    CString query_select = "SELECT * FROM ";
    query_select += nometab;
    QString query_insert = "INSERT INTO ";
    if (nometab.Compare("OFFSET") == 0)
        query_insert += nometabtmp;
    else
        query_insert += nometab;

    query_insert += " VALUES (";//inserire i campi


    for (int i = 0; i < n_fields; i++)
    {
        if (i < n_fields - 1)
            query_insert += "?, ";
        else
            query_insert += "?) ";

    }

    if (dbSet.IsOpen())
        dbSet.Close();

    dbSet.Open(dbOpenDynaset, query_select);

    qryInsert->prepare(query_insert);
    ........//other code to prepare a query
    qryInsert->addBindValue((myvalue));
    if (!qryInsert->exec()){...}
```

Do you have any idea? Thank very much!

Comment: Is it a typo or are you mixing CString and QString?

Comment: What kind of exception does it say this is? Access violation (`C0000005`) or some other?

Comment: Cstring used to connection on db access, while QString used to connection on db postgresql. I'm doing access to postgresql conversion and I serialize and deserialize blob data.

Comment: Yep, this exception 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x005B4000.

Comment: what's the role of `pgAdmin-4` here?

Comment: Can I delete/clean  my qryInsert after exec?